# Is it efficient to create unlimited objects in a loop during streaming?

Tags: python, streaming

Is it a good idea to instantiate an object in streaming w.r.t to time & space efficiency, as follows?

```
while streaming:
    latest_log = get_latest_log_from_stream()
    obj = Engine(latest_log)
    obj.run()
```

or object creation in infinite streaming should always be avoided, as follows?

```
obj = Engine()
while streaming:
    latest_log = get_latest_log_from_stream()
    obj.run(latest_log)
```

Where the class `Engine` is responsible to detect anomaly associated with the given log.

Comment: without knowing what `Engine` is, its impossible to answer this.

Comment: @Sayse I have edited the question. Let me know if you want to know more.

Comment: Please post the `init()` function code of `Engine`, and `run()`, so we can properly help you.

Comment: [You can just profile your code yourself using `cProfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#the-python-profilers).